# Execute python script on remote windows client

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I'm using `paramiko` to execute commands on a remote windows server. I'm able to execute commands like `dir` and extract the output, but executing a `python` script seems to fail. No error message is thrown.

Here is my code snippet:

```
def ssh_connect(ip,user,pwd):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=pwd)
        return ssh


def execute_command(device_details, command):
       ip = device_details.get('ip')
       username = device_details.get('username')
       password = device_details.get('password')
       ssh_ns_obj = ssh_connect(ip, username, password)
       ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_ns_obj.exec_command(command)
       print ssh_stderr.read()
       return ssh_stdout.read()

device_details = dict()
device_details['ip'] = 'a.b.c.d'
device_details['username'] = 'Administrator'
device_details['password'] = 'pass'

command_1 = "cmd /c mkdir asdf"
output = execute_command(device_details, command_1)

command_2 = 'cmd /c "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:\pythonattempt\try.py"'
output = execute_command(device_details, command_2)
```

Here is my `try.py` mentioned in `command_2`:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Hey, just starting")

    os.system(r"mkdir C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\x")
    print ("hey, file is up")

    with open(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\x.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("This is a line of a file")
```

`command_1` executes successfully, i'm able to see the directory created on my windows machine. But `command_2` does not throw any error, but also doesn't get executed.

I know because the `x.txt` or folder `x` does not get created.

I've installed the `freeSSHd` service on Windows. I'm able to `ssh` into my Windows machine and execute the exact same command, and it's working.

See image below:

[image]

How do i proceed?

Comment: Yes @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl, i've made the change. Also, `ssh_stderr` returns a blank string, so i assume no error

Comment: Read it by doing `ssh_stderr.read()`, as seen in the code snippet now. 
Which ssh server - `freeSSHd`.
Does it work  when you ssh and execute? Yes.

Comment: What SSH client is that? Can you do `plink username@host cmd /c "C:\...\python.exe c:\...\try.py`? (plink is Windows command-line SSH client from PuTTY package, you can also use `ssh` from OpenSSH package with the same syntax).

Comment: without `cmd /c`, i get the error : `Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that `\t` is a special character and when i was trying to execute `C:\pythonattempt\try.py`, the `\t` was taken as a special character.

I realized when i opened the same script on `sublime` instead of on `vi` and there was a difference in color!